# При нажатии на первую ячейку любой строки, изменялся selectedRow

Tags: jquery

Имеется код для изменения selectedRow.

```
$(function() {
    addOnclickToDatatableRows();
});

function addOnclickToDatatableRows() {
    var trs = $('[id*=dataTable] tbody:first tr').get();

    for (var i = 0; i < trs.length; i++) {
        trs[i].onclick = new Function("selectRow(this)");
    }
}

function selectRow(tr) { 
    var $input = $('[id*=selectedRow]');
    $input.val(""+(tr.rowIndex-1));
    $input.change();
}
```

Он выполняется при нажатии на любую ячейку строки, а мне нужно при нажатии только на первую ячейку. Я новичок в jqyery, выручайте.

Answer (score 0):

Замените

```
var trs = $('[id*=dataTable] tbody:first tr').get();
```

на

```
var trs = $('[id*=dataTable] tr td:first-child').get();
```